# Fixed Points Problem with 2D Mapping

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, map

I have been playing with the mapping given by

```
      henon[{x_, y_}] := Module[{A1, A2, A3},
   A1 = A2 = A3 = {};
   AppendTo[A1, {x + a y/2, y}];
   AppendTo[A2, {A1[[1]][[1]], A1[[1]][[2]] + a (4 A1[[1]][[1]] + A1[[1]][[1]]^2)}];
   AppendTo[A3, {A2[[1]][[1]] + a A2[[1]][[2]]/2, A2[[1]][[2]]}];
   Return[A3[[1]]];
   ];
```

which is nothing but a version of the classical Hénon map. The parameter value $a=1$ is a period doubling bifurcation for the stable equilibrium point $(-4.0)$ of this map. This is clear in the graphs bellow, where $a=.9$ for the first and $a=1.0005$ for the second.

[image]

[image: Fixed points very easy to spot]

My problem is that I need to find the coordinates of those fixed points. When I type

```
a = .9;
Solve[{(henon[{x, y}][[1]]) == x, (henon[{x, y}][[2]]) == y}, {x, y}]
```

I get the correct result of

```
> {{x -> -4., y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}}
```

But when I try to do that after the bifurcation,

```
a = 1.00005;
    Solve[{(henon[{x, y}][[1]]) == x, (henon[{x, y}][[2]]) == y}, {x, y}]
```

I get

```
> {{x -> -5.74637*10^18, y -> 4.05451*10^17}, {x -> -5.74637*10^18, 
  y -> 4.05451*10^17}, {x -> -4., y -> -4.96939*10^-17}, {x -> 0., 
  y -> 0.}}
```

Which looks to me like nonsense. It seems Mathematica is unable to detect those fixed points emerging after the bifurcation occurs. What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If others wish to play with this (interesting question) may want to use `henon1[a_, {x0_, y0_}] := Block[{x1, y1},x1 = x0 + a y0/2;y1 = y0 + a (4 x1 + x1^2);{x1 + a y1/2, y1}]` which is identical to `henon` above

Comment: @Manuel--Moe--G Thanks! Elegance was never one of my characteristics.

Comment: Note you can use `AspectRatio -> Automatic` on your plots to keep the circles circular.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are correct.  The first two solutions occur "at infinity" but your last two (after `Chop`) are `{x->-4, y->0}` and `{x->0, y->0}`, as is correct.

Comment: So why doesn't Mathematica give me the other fixed points that arise after the bifurcation?

Comment: What do you expect the other fixed points to be?  Solving analytically finds only the points `{-4,0}` and `{0,0}`, for any value of `a`.

Comment: (`Reduce[Thread[henon[{x, y}] == {x, y}]` shows this to be true)

Comment: Playing a little bit with FixedPointList tells me one of them is around $\{-3.99986, -0.0471424\}$, and the other is symmetric in $y$.

Comment: You're experiencing numerical errors.  Try with arbitrary-precision or exact arithmetic (for both the seed and `a`), and you'll see that the analytic solution is backed up.

Comment: Actually I'm not having any errors at all. I was being ignorant... After reading about the theory I learned that such points that arise should NOT be fixed points of this map anyway. They're fixed points of the square map.